# Creating a simple 1-row Spark DataFrame with Java API

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Scala, I can create a single-row DataFrame from an in-memory string like so:

```
val stringAsList = List("buzz")
val df = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(jsonValues).toDF("fizz")
df.show()
```

When `df.show()` runs, it outputs:

```
+-----+
| fizz|
+-----+
| buzz|
+-----+
```

**Now I'm trying to do this from inside a Java class.** Apparently `JavaRDD`s don't have a `toDF(String)` method. I've tried:

```
List<String> stringAsList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringAsList.add("buzz");
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext);
DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sparkContext
    .parallelize(stringAsList), StringType);
df.show();
```

...but still seem to be coming up short. Now when `df.show();` executes, I get:

```
++
||
++
||
++
```

(An empty DF.) So I ask: Using the **Java API**, how do I read an in-memory string into a DataFrame that has only 1 row and 1 column in it, **and also specify the name of that column?** (So that the `df.show()` is identical to the Scala one above)?

Comment: I think, in your first example, you have a typo and should replace jsonValues -> stringAsList   I'm still new to this syntax though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating List to Rdd and than create Schema which will contain column name.

There might be other ways as well, it's just one of them.

```
List<String> stringAsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        stringAsList.add("buzz");

JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(stringAsList).map((String row) -> {
                return RowFactory.create(row);
            });

StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] { DataTypes.createStructField("fizz", DataTypes.StringType, false) });

DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema).toDF();
df.show();

//+----+
|fizz|
+----+
|buzz|
```

Answer (score 14):

I have created 2 examples for Spark 2 if you need to upgrade:

Simple Fizz/Buzz (or foe/bar - old generation :) ):

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Build a DataFrame from Scratch").master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();

    List<String> stringAsList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringAsList.add("bar");

    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

    JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(stringAsList).map((String row) -> RowFactory.create(row));

    // Creates schema
    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(
            new StructField[] { DataTypes.createStructField("foe", DataTypes.StringType, false) });

    Dataset<Row> df = spark.sqlContext().createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema).toDF();
```

2x2 data:

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Build a DataFrame from Scratch").master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();

    List<String[]> stringAsList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringAsList.add(new String[] { "bar1.1", "bar2.1" });
    stringAsList.add(new String[] { "bar1.2", "bar2.2" });

    JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

    JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(stringAsList).map((String[] row) -> RowFactory.create(row));

    // Creates schema
    StructType schema = DataTypes
            .createStructType(new StructField[] { DataTypes.createStructField("foe1", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                    DataTypes.createStructField("foe2", DataTypes.StringType, false) });

    Dataset<Row> df = spark.sqlContext().createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema).toDF();
```

Code can be downloaded from: https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.labs.spark.

Comment: How can this be done for mixed data type ? Let's say if values to create data frame is "bar1.1" (String) and 10(Int)

Answer (score 1):

Building on what @jgp suggested. If you want to do this for **mixed types** you can do:

```
List<Tuple2<Integer, Boolean>> mixedTypes = Arrays.asList(
                new Tuple2<>(1, false),
                new Tuple2<>(1, false),
                new Tuple2<>(1, false));

JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(mixedTypes).map(row -> RowFactory.create(row._1, row._2));

StructType mySchema = new StructType()
                .add("id", DataTypes.IntegerType, false)
                .add("flag", DataTypes.BooleanType, false);

Dataset<Row> df = spark.sqlContext().createDataFrame(rowRDD, mySchema).toDF();
```

This might help with the @jdk2588 's question.

Comment: I have stumbled over the same issue and it seems that Spark MLLib v. 3.0.2 does not provide a method `sparkContext.parallelize()` that takes only a list as parameter. So, it would be good to know with which version this code is working (applies to the other replies, too).

Comment: Why do you do a `toDF()` after `createDataFrame` ?  `createDataFrame` isn't enough ??

Answer (score 1):

This post here provides a solution that doesn't go through `sparkContext.parallelize(...)`: https://timepasstechies.com/create-spark-dataframe-java-list/