# How to create a Spark UDF in Java which accepts array of Strings?

Tags: java, apache-spark

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31036567/pass-array-as-an-udf-parameter-in-spark-sql) for Scala, and it does not help me as I am working with Java API. I have been literally throwing everything and the kitchen sink at it, so this was my approach:

```
List<String> sourceClasses = new ArrayList<String>();
//Add elements
List<String> targetClasses = new ArrayList<String>();
//Add elements

dataset = dataset.withColumn("Transformer", callUDF(
    "Transformer",
    lit((String[])sourceClasses.toArray())
        .cast(DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType)),
    lit((String[])targetClasses.toArray())
        .cast(DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType))
));
```

And for my UDF declaration:

```
public class Transformer implements UDF2<Seq<String>, Seq<String>, String> {


//  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public String call(Seq<String> sourceClasses, Seq<String> targetClasses)
    throws Exception {
```

When I run the code, the execution does not proceed past the UDF call, which is expected because I am not being able to match up the types. Please help me in this regard.

### EDIT

I tried the solution suggested by @Oli. However, I got the following exception:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$261: (array<string>, array<string>) => string)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.project_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Seq
at com.esrx.dqm.uuid.UUIDTransformerEngine$1.call(UUIDTransformerEngine.java:1)
at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration$$anonfun$261.apply(UDFRegistration.scala:774)
... 22 more
```

This line specifically seems to be indicative of a problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Seq
```

Comment: Could you add in your question: the stackTrace and the schema of your dataset please ?

Comment: @dnej, I created just a 1 row dataframe referring this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967194/creating-a-simple-1-row-spark-dataframe-with-java-api. The execution just blocks at the UDF call. It does not terminate, nor does it throw an exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understand from the type of your UDF, you are trying to create a UDF that takes two arrays as inputs and returns a string.

In java, that's a bit painful but manageable.

Let's say that you want to join both arrays and link them with the word AND. You could define the UDF as follows:

```java
UDF2 my_udf2 = new UDF2<WrappedArray<String>, WrappedArray<String>, String>() {
    public String call(WrappedArray<String> a1, WrappedArray a2) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList(JavaConverters
            .asJavaCollectionConverter(a1)
            .asJavaCollection());
        ArrayList<String> l2 = new ArrayList(JavaConverters
            .asJavaCollectionConverter(a2)
            .asJavaCollection());
        return l1.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")) +
             " AND " +
             l2.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }
};
```

Note that you need to use scala `WrappedArray` in the signature in the method and transform them in the body of the method with `JavaConverters` to be able to manipulate them in Java. Here are the required import just in case.

```java
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray;
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;
```

Then you can register the UDF can use it with Spark. To be able to use it, I created a sample dataframe and two dummy arrays from the 'id' column. Note that it can also work with the `lit` function as you were trying to do in your question.

```java
spark.udf().register("my_udf2", my_udf2, DataTypes.StringType);

String[] data = {"abcd", "efgh", "ijkl"};

spark.range(3)
    .withColumn("id", col("id").cast("string"))
    .withColumn("array", functions.array(col("id"), col("id")))
    .withColumn("string_of_arrays",
          functions.callUDF("my_udf2", col("array"), lit(data)))
    .show(false);
```

which yields:

```
+---+------+----------------------+
|id |array |string_of_arrays      |
+---+------+----------------------+
|0  |[0, 0]|0,0 AND abcd,efgh,ijkl|
|1  |[1, 1]|1,1 AND abcd,efgh,ijkl|
|2  |[2, 2]|2,2 AND abcd,efgh,ijkl|
+---+------+----------------------+
```

In Spark >= 2.3, you could also do it like this:

```
UserDefinedFunction my_udf2 = udf(
    (WrappedArray<String> s1, WrappedArray<String> s2) -> "some_string",
    DataTypes.StringType
);

df.select(my_udf2.apply(col("a1"), col("a2")).show(false);
```

Comment: Hi @Oli, can we pass actual Java arrays or lists as lit parameters into the UDF? That is actually my use case.

Comment: I was not sure so I just tried. It works. I edited the answer with an example ;)

Comment: I tried your solution, but got the exception whose stacktrace I have mentioned in an edit in my post.

Comment: Strange... The code worked for me with Spark 2.2.1 :-/ Let me edit my post with something more robust.

Comment: I am using Spark 2.4.4.

Comment: I modified my answer. We usually use `WrappedArray` for UDF in scala. In java I was not sure. After the facts I am actually quite surprised that it was working on my side with `Seq`...

Comment: I used the code snippet for Spark >=2.3 that you provided, and the problem went back to what I had initially: the execution just stalls without providing either an output or exception.

Comment: It's the same. Execution is not proceeding beyond the point when we call the action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203106/discussion-between-oli-and-abhishek).

Comment: Unfortunately access to chat is denied from within my organization.

Comment: Nevermind. It feels like we are addressing a different issue from the one described in your question. The casting issue seems to be fixed. Now (let me know if i am mistaken), the problem is that the execution never ends. It's hard to determine what's wrong now without looking at the full code. We could close this post to avoid adding some noise with other issues and you could ask a new question with the code you have now and the problem you have now. If that's ok for you, don't hesitate to post the link here, I'll try to have a look.